Is there a characterization of monos and epis in (co)slice and arrow categories?
I'm working through Borceux's Categorical Algebra, and I'm curious about problem 1.11.10. It says to characterize the monomorphisms, epimorphisms, and isomorphisms of $C/I$, $I/C$, and $\textrm{Arr}(C)$ (slice, coslice, and arrow categories). It's clear that isomorphisms are "just the isomorphisms of $C$" appropriately restricted (pairs of them in the case of $\textrm{Arr}(C)$). Furthermore, epis/monos from $C$ are clearly preserved whenever one (or a pair) can be found in the new category. But it seems like the process of constructing these categories might not be reflective of epis/monos, in the sense that some arrows (or pairs) might become epis/monos due to losing some arrows that could witness their non-epi/mono status in $C$.
Is there a better characterization of monos/epis in (co)slice and arrow categories, or is this about all that can be said in general?
Edit: It seems like in the category of sets, the projection $C/I\to C$ preserves monics, but not epics (consider any arrow in $C/I$ with codomain $Id_I: I\to I$, then any given arrow, $f$, that can be post-composed with it must be an iso and is necessarily the unique arrow from its domain ($Id_I$) to its inverse ($f^{-1}$)). The dual is true for $I/C$ and epics.

Monos and epis are reflected by faithful functors, such as the projection $\mathcal{C}/X \to \mathcal{C}$ or $X/\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}$.

I agree. That's a clean way of arguing what I said above. In those terms, my question is whether the projection map preserves monos and epis (or failing that, if there's some other neat characterization of the monos and epis)

Monomorphisms in slice categories and epimorphisms in coslice categories are always preserved by the forgetful functor. The forgetful functor has a right adjoint (in the case of a slice category) or a left adjoint (in the case of a coslice category) if binary products (respectively, coproducts) with the given object exist, so the forgetful functor would also preserve epimorphisms (respectively, monomorphisms) in that case.

Also, for an arrow category, the domain functor always has a left adjoint (hence always preserves monomorphisms), while the codomain functor always has a right adjoint (hence always preserves epimorphisms). The domain functor has a right adjoint (hence preserves epimorphisms) if the category has a terminal object, while the codomain functor has a left adjoint (hence preserves monomorphisms) if the category has an initial object.

That's a neat and satisfying explanation. It fits with the bit of work I did on the arrow category of Set (although it's a bit trickier bashing all the possible cases with different test objects). Thanks to both of you for the help!
